# How to print out Map<String, List<Object>> in Java

Tags: java, view, controller, java-stream, dao

I'm attempting to print out the contents of an object called DVD via my View class, but unfortunately I am not able to. I am trying to fix the `getDVDByDirectorSortedByMpaaRating()` in the `DVDLibraryController` class, which requires a method in the `DVDLibraryView` class.

Function in `ServiceLayer` implementation:

```
@Override
public Map<String, List<DVD>> getDVDByDirectorSortedByMpaaRating(String directorName) {
    return dvds.values()
        .stream()
        .filter(s -> s.getDirectorName().equalsIgnoreCase(directorName))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DVD::getMpaaRating));
}
```

Attempt to call this function in the Controller:

```
private void getDVDByDirectorSortedByMpaaRating() throws DVDLibraryPersistenceException{
    String director = view.getDirectorName();
    Map<String, List<DVD>> dvdList = service.getDVDByDirectorSortedByMpaaRating(director);
    view.displayDVDsByDirectorsSortedByMpaaRating(dvdList.toString());
}
```

I'm not sure how I can finish the method in the Controller, and I have no idea how to print the results from the View class.

For now, here is the start of the method that prints the results in the View:

```
public void displayDVDsByDirectorsSortedByMpaaRating(String directors){
        io.print(directors);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit: Results of printout are below:**

> {R=[DVDLibrary.dto.DVD@37bba400], PG=[DVDLibrary.dto.DVD@179d3b25]}

It's definitely sorting by Mpaa Rating, but the printouts are not working correctly.

Comment: Would `toString` work for you?

Comment: `System.out.println(dvdList);` unless you want a specific format.

Comment: If you want a DVD to print a certain thing, override the `toString` method in `DVD`. Otherwise the default is for it to print the `className@hashcode` of the object.